# Unable to prove $\frac{\cos^2 A -\sin^2 A}{\cos A-\sin A} = \sin A+\cos A$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

For the identity $$\frac{\cos^2 A -\sin^2 A}{\cos A-\sin A} = \sin A+\cos A$$

I am unable to reach this even using the Pythagorean identity. 
Can someone please help!

Comment: Hint: $x^2-y^2 = (x+y)(x-y)$. (Sometimes, the trickiest part of trig is algebra. :)

Comment: are you sure you need to ask this question?

Comment: Hint: $\sin A$ is a number, and so is $\cos A$.

Answer (score 6):

**HINT**
use $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$

So $$\cos^2(A)-\sin^2(A)=(\cos(A)-\sin(A))(\cos(A)+\sin(A))$$

Comment: Nice useful answer - I think it would have been even better with just the HINT, leaving work for the OP.